# Multiple REST API calls in succession returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to query some JIRA issues using a the `jira-connector` package.
I'm running into issues with the data returned not being defined until after everything else is executed in my code. I'm not sure if this is some issue with concurrency, but I can't for the life of me figure out where and how I'm messing up.

If inside the  `getJiraTimeEstimations` function only call the `getJiraTimeEstimate` once it works just fine and I get access to the data to use further down in the program. It is when I'm trying to do it inside a `map` or  `foreach` where I iterate over the `Array.from(dataFromMaconomy.keys())` array that I seem to run into issues.

My understanding is that adding `.then().catch()` in the `getJiraTimeEstimate` function should be enough to stop it from continuing to run before all the calls are finished? Or am I misunderstanding how asynchronous calls work in Node and JS?

I've also tried converting it to an `async getJiraTimeEstimations` and adding an `await` infront of the search. But it doesn't seem to work either.

I am not populating the `dataFromMaconomy` array as I'm debugging. Which is what I was trying to do with the log statement. The log statement just prints `undefined` right now. But if I only call it with a single item from the `rks` array then it works fine.

```
function getJiraTimeEstimate(taskNumber, jiraClient) {
  jiraClient.search.search({
    jql: `id = ${taskNumber}`,
  }).then((res) => res.issues[0].fields.timeoriginalestimate).catch((err) => err);
}

function getJiraTimeEstimations(dataFromMaconomy) {
  const settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'konfig.json'), 'utf8'));
  const privateKeyData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, settings.jira.consumerPrivateKeyFile), 'utf8');
  const jira = new JiraClient({
    host: settings.jira.server,
    strictSSL: false, // Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    oauth: {
      consumer_key: settings.jira.consumerKey,
      private_key: privateKeyData,
      token: settings.jira.accessToken,
      token_secret: settings.jira.accessTokenSecret,
    },
  });
  console.log('getting time estimations from Jira');
  const dataFromMaconomyWithJira = [];
  const rks = Array.from(dataFromMaconomy.keys());
  rks.map((rk) => console.log(getJiraTimeEstimate(rk, jira)));
  return dataFromMaconomyWithJira;
}


function generateData(){
  const dataWithJira = getJiraTimeEstimations(convertedData);
  // More functions where I use the data from getJiraTimeEstimations
  // This gets run before all of the getJiraTimeEstimations have finished getting the data.
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what is not working. Do you expect `dataWithJira` in the `generateData()` to have the data (it has none because the array is never popuplated)? Or the issue is about something else?

Comment: @PawelPsztyc Sorry I am not populating the data as I'm debugging. Which is what I was trying to do with the log statement. The log statement just prints `undefined` in the case above. But if I only call it on a single item from the rks array then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving your clarification in the comment, the `getJiraTimeEstimate()` function does not return anything. Try:

```
function getJiraTimeEstimate(taskNumber, jiraClient) {
  return jiraClient.search.search({
    jql: `id = ${taskNumber}`,
  }).then((res) => res.issues[0].fields.timeoriginalestimate).catch((err) => err);
}
```

Also, you mentioned trying async / await but without luck. The async version of it would be:

```
async function getJiraTimeEstimate(taskNumber, jiraClient) {
  try {
    const res = await jiraClient.search.search({
      jql: `id = ${taskNumber}`,
    });
    return res.issues[0].fields.timeoriginalestimate;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'm embarrassed that I forgot to return it from `getJiraTimeEstimate()`. However now I've just got a bunch of promises in an array. In the `generateData()` method I can inspect the returned data after pushing the value from the jira search. This gives me an array of promises. I have to do an `await Promise.all()` on the returned data array. But thanks a lot it's working now!

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 it happens to everyone so don't beat yourself. Yes, this results with an array of promises that you have to resolve. This is how this work.